# How would I know the zone file from which the DNS query has been answered?

Tags: domain-name-system, logging, bind

I have a BIND DNS Setup with several closely similar, yet different zone files with custom 'views' enabled. Is there a way I can log or find from which zone file [in the hundreds of zone files] has the query been answered?

Answer (score 2):

From none of them; all zone data is in memory.

Once the zones are loaded (on startup and/or reload), the files are no longer referenced.

Of course, BIND logs both the query source address (the client) and the response source address (the view's IP) - you could conceivably correlate these with your knowledge of the zone and view layout.

Comment: I understand what you said, but the problem is when I am querying for a particular domain, I am getting incorrect data though the zone file has the right content. So, I would like to know from which zone ile is it fetching that particular answer from. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What does "getting incorrect data" mean ? BIND will serve the data you request.

Comment: For example, I have IP 1.2.3.4 for a domain, BIND is returning 1.2.3.5 for some reason. It could be that BIND is forwarding the request or getting the information by recursion, etc. I just want to track what bind is doing when I run the query. I have enabled 'debug' in named.conf which doesn't seem to be of much help as the data from the logs is vague. Can you suggest some other logging token?

Comment: Logging is not optional if you want to understand what BIND is doing. Spend some time learning how to set it up properly, then study its output.